# Where should i write my javascript code in angular 4 for a component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, semantic-ui

I am making an angular app and in that I have a component in which I have added a alert message using semantic-ui and to dismiss that message I have to write a specific provided by semantic itself.
I am not sure where should I write that code in order to make it work.

my html code:

```
<div class="ui negative message" style="margin: 20px 20% 0 20%;">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        We're sorry we can't apply that discount
    </div>
    <p>That offer has expired</p>
</div>
```

script:

```
$('.message .close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.message').transition('fade');
});
```

Comment: are you using typescript or js file?

Comment: I am using typscript for the component . I want to add run this javascript code in my component

Comment: You would completely change your code to have angular listen and handle the click and animation

Comment: check [this](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2017/02/15/jquery-with-angular-cli.html). maybe that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use already adopted for Angular semantic-ui library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-semantic-ui. It's already wrapped in Angular so you don't need to worry about jQuery.

Angular doesn't recommend to manipulate DOM by jQuery or raw JavaScript. It has DOM abstraction services for it. You can read more here: https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02

So even if you wrap your jQuery code in Angular it will be bad from the point of best practices.I would really suggest to use ng2-semantic-ui. It will save your time.

Answer (score 0):

Better create your own animation transition. Here is how

In your component.ts file do this:

```
import { trigger, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  animations: [
    trigger(
      'enterAnimation', [
        transition(':enter', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}))
        ])
      ]
    )
  ]
})
export class App {
  show:boolean = true; //The error message is displayed by default
}
```

So now you have the code to fade in and fade out. Now you need to change the value of your show boolean when the button is clicked. So you do this in your component.html

```
<div class="ui negative message" *ngIf="show" [@enterAnimation] style="margin: 20px 20% 0 20%;">
    <i class="close icon" (click)="show = !show"></i>
    <div class="header">
        We're sorry we can't apply that discount
    </div>
    <p>That offer has expired</p>
</div>
```

This way you do not have to use jquery in your angular app.